# Jenkins error: docker client must be run with elevated privilege

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

In trying to build a basic **Jenskins** pipeline in **Windows OS**, I encounter the following error.

[Privileges not provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idloV.png)

The code for my JenkinsFile is:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Code') {
      steps {
        git(url: 'https://github.com/Sammamm/WeatherApp', branch: 'main')
      }
    }

    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        bat 'docker build -t react-docker .'
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        bat 'echo \'Testing...\''
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        bat 'echo \'Deploying...\''
      }
    }

  }
}
```

The code for my DockerFile:

```
# adds node as the base image
FROM node:20-alpine

# creates a seperate directory
WORKDIR /app

# copies the packages from our project to the new directory
COPY package*.json ./

# runs the command npm install
# to install all dependencies
RUN npm install

# copies other files
COPY ..

# exposes it to port 5173
EXPOSE 5173

# runs command "npm run dev" to start the app
CMD npm run dev
```

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the logs, not the image

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, your user lacks privileges to run docker. Check which user your Jenkins pipeline is running from and see if they are different from your admin user.

If the user that is being used to run this pipeline is different from your admin user (such as a Jenkins user), you will have to [add the user to the docker-users group](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/#install-docker-desktop-on-windows). Follow the instructions on the documentation.